# Make image link open in new window in php file

Tags: javascript, php, html, hyperlink, onclick

Hi I have a website that has a banner that i want to link to another website of mine, but I want it to open in a new window. I also want the cursor to be a hand in all browsers as well. I tried the target = "_blank" method but I don't believe that is right. How can I do this in PHP?

here is the code

I know there are some answers similar to this question but none have solved my problem

```
    <div class="banner-part" onclick="location.href='www.blabla.org/' target="_blank";" style="cursor: pointer;" style="cursor: hand;"><img src="<?php bloginfo('url') ?>/images/banner.png" alt="" /></div>
```

Comment: Why are you using a `div` instead of an `a` but treating it as such? and why do you have a closing `</a>` tag there? This snippet is quite messy...

Comment: I think PHP is a back-end language & it has nothing to do with front-end. Your problem can be solved using javascript

Comment: What is the point which stopped you from using `<a>` which is specifically for this purpose?

Comment: `target="_blank"` **is** the correct way to have a link open in a new window.

Comment: @user3688814 Please correct your code for us to answer. As Damien mentioned you have an extra `</a>` and no `<a>`

Comment: my apologies I corrected it. (facepalm)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're making a bit of a mess there. You're forcing a `<div>` to act like an `<a>`, when you could achieve the same thing with a sprinkle of CSS:

```
<a href="http://www.blabla.org" target="_blank" class="banner-part">
    <img src="<?php bloginfo('url') ?>/images/banner.png" alt="" />
</a>
```

And make the `<a>` a **block** element through CSS, without needing to put a block element (`<div>`) inside an inline element (`<a>`), which is *invalid* html in doctypes apart from HTML5 (though the browsers won't complain much)

```
a.banner-part {
 display:block;
}
```

Comment: Actually flow content in `a` [is allowed](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/text-level-semantics.html#the-a-element) in HTML5.

Comment: HTML5 turns some rules around sometimes...Thanks for the correction!

Answer (score 1):

```
<a href='//www.blabla.org/' target="_blank"><div class="banner-part"><img src="<?php bloginfo('url') ?>/images/banner.png" alt="" /></div></a>
```

Use the div inside the `a` tag

Answer (score 1):

`target` is not a valid property for `div` element. Try this:

```
<a href="YOUR_PATH_HERE" target="_blank">
  <div class="banner-part">
    <img src="<?php bloginfo('url') ?>/images/banner.png" alt="" />
  </div>
</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your HTML is broken:

```
<div [...snip...] /></a>
 ^^^------------------^
```

You open a `div` tag, then close an `a`